# Tutorial: Understanding a Topic: run rxgraph I got a nameError

Tags: ros, rxgraph

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I am following the ROS tutorial and now come to the Understanding ROS Topics. When I key in rxgraph, it give me

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/btian/ros/ros/bin/rxgraph", line 36, in 
rxgraph.rxgraph_main()
File "/home/btian/ros/rx/rxgraph/src/rxgraph/**init**.py", line 61, in rxgraph_main
print >> sys.stderr, "Graphviz does not appear to be installed on your system. Please run:\n\n\trosdep install rosgraph\n\nto install the necessary dependencies on your system"
NameError: global name 'sys' is not defined

But \n\n\trosdep does not exist. I tried import sys also, does not help.
any idea how to get over this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12481/tutorial:-understanding-a-topic:-run-rxgraph-i-got-a-nameerror/) by [tianb03](https://answers.ros.org/users/1587/tianb03/) on ROS Answers with karma: 710 on 2011-12-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed graphvis in synaptic ...

Done. it works now.

---

Originally posted by [tianb03](https://answers.ros.org/users/1587/tianb03/) with karma: 710 on 2011-12-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2